# Sum of last 3 elements for x elements in a list as a new list [python 3]

Tags: python, pandas, function, sum, list-comprehension

I have a broader problem that I have boiled down to one aspect I am stuck on, I want to have a rolling sum of the last three elements from position "x" in a list of unknown length. With the first three elements not having a sum containing the xn, xn-1, or xn-2 values.

`List_A = [x, x1, x2, x3, ..., xn]`

`Desired_Output = [0, x, x + x1, x + x1 + x2,..., xn-3 + xn-2 + xn-1]`

A number example would be:

`List_A = [1, 0, 1, 3, 1, 1]`

`Desired_Output = [0, 1, 1, 2, 4, 5]`

I have tried writing it in a list comprehension, using the sum function and slicing to no avail

`Desired_Output = [sum(List_A[x:x+3]) for x in List_A]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to create an iterable that will return a slice of 3 elements at a time from `List_A`. We use `[max(0, i - 3):i]` so that when `i - 3` is less than `0` we start the slice at `0` - when `i` is `0` the slice will be `[0:0]` which will return an empty list, is this what you want, the first element will always be `0`?

```
[List_A[max(0, i - 3):i] for i in range(len(List_A))]
```

Then you just need to `sum` the slices

```
[sum(List_A[max(0, i - 3):i]) for i in range(len(List_A))]
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this is exactly what I was trying to do.